# Send row info to angularjs controller when checkbox in row is clicked

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox

I have some html code which uses angularjs to show a table. On this table, there is a checkbox on each row.

The table looks like this;
[image]

Here is the html code.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="CheckCtrl">
    <table class="table table-hover data-table sort display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="Serial_">
                Serial
            </th>
            <th class="Name_">
                Name
            </th>
            <th class="ID_">
                ID
            </th>
            <th class="On_off_">
                On/off
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in check_items">
            <td>{{item.SERIAL}}</td>
            <td>{{item.NAME}}</td>
            <td>{{item.ID}}</td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.ON_OFF == '1'"></td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my angularjs controller code.

```
controller('CheckCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'configuration', 
    function ($scope, $http, $configuration) {
        var url_api = $configuration.host + "cloe/webroot/cloe-cloud/app/API.json";
        $http.get(url_api).success(function(data)
        {
            $scope.check_items = data;
        });
```

This is what I want. When a user clicks on a checkbox, information regarding all the items on that particular row belonging to the clicked checkbox is sent to a angualrjs controller function for processing. This information should include the Serial, Name, ID and new state of On/Off after clicking on the checkbox.

I am using angularjs v1 and twitter bootstrap.

EDIT: Edited the original question details to indicate that the row information should be sent whenever the checkbox is clicked and not only when the checkbox is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use **ng-change** to send row data to controller as object.
After that, you can retrieve row data as following:

```
var serial = row.SERIAL;
var name = row.NAME;
var id = row.ID;
var onOff = row.ON_OFF;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="CheckCtrl">
    <table class="table table-hover data-table sort display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="Serial_">
                Serial
            </th>
            <th class="Name_">
                Name
            </th>
            <th class="ID_">
                ID
            </th>
            <th class="On_off_">
                On/off
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in check_items">
            <td>{{item.SERIAL}}</td>
            <td>{{item.NAME}}</td>
            <td>{{item.ID}}</td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.ON_OFF == '1'" ng-click="rowSelected(item)"></td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('app',[]);
  app.controller('CheckCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
      $scope.check_items = 
        [
           {
             SERIAL:'Test Serial',
             NAME:'Test Name',
             ID : 10,
             ON_OFF : '1'
           }
        ];

      $scope.rowSelected = function(row)
      {
          console.log(row);
      };
   }]);
  </script>
```

Comment: Natiq, thanks for the answer. Upvoted. It is almost what I want. I was not clear in my question details. I still have a minor problem. I would like to row information to be sent whenever the checkbox is clicked. Your code sends row information when the checkbox is enabled but when the checkbox is disabled, nothing is sent.
I will edit my question details to be more clear.

Comment: @user91579631, I have used condition(**if(row.selected)**). If you want to retrieve data in both of selected and unselected state, you can remove condition. I will update my answer.

Comment: Your code works perfectly well. When I transferred to my code, the first click does not work. However, subsequent clicks work fine. I am still struggling with that. I cannot see what is the difference at the moment. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: May I ask why do you use `ng-model="item.selected"`?

Comment: @user91579631, I have used it to determine checkbox state, selected(true) or not(false) . But, after update, it is not required

Comment: Natiq, would you mind updating your answer to use ng-click instead of ng-change? user8461258's answer solved my problem where the first click does not work but subsequent clicks do. I will select your answer as the answer since your answer did most of the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe use something like this,

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.ON_OFF == '1'" ng-change="checkSubmit(item.serial,item.name,item.id,item.on_off)">
```

**JS:**

```
function checkSubmit(serial,name,id,on_off){
```

`...`
`/*Processing can happen now with the parameters obtained*/`
`...}`

**NOTE:** The case of the variables may be wrong

Answer (score 1):

Some modification to the answer provided by Natiq.

Modify this line

```
<td> <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.ON_OFF == '1'" ng-model="item.selected" ng-change="rowSelected(item)"></td>
```

to

```
<td> <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.ON_OFF == '1'" ng-model="item.selected" ng-click="rowSelected(item)"></td>
```

The modification is from `ng-change` to `ng-click`. This will solve your problem where the first click does not work but only subsequent clicks work based on the comments posted. Using ng-click ensures that every click will be detected.